# How to pass an Element's ID to an Anonymous Function?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I am trying to add an event listener to elements that have the same class by doing something like this...

```
// Add listener's to all elements that have a class name of "foo"
var foos = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
for (i = 0; i < foos.length; i++) {
    var fooId = foos[i].id;
    foos[i].addEventListener('click', function(){doFoo(fooId)});
}

function doFoo(id) {
    document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += "<li>You clicked Foo " + id + "</li>";
}
```

The above JavaScript works other than the fact that the anonymous function argument "fooId" will always evaluate to the id of the last element of the collection - instead of the id of the item in scope of the loop.

How do I pass the id of the element id to the anonymous function parameter?

In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6e4NC/ you will see that no matter which Div you click, the JavaScript will always claimed that you clicked the last Div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var foos = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
for (i = 0; i < foos.length; i++) {
   var fooId = foos[i].id;
   var f = function (fooId) {
       return function (){doFoo(fooId)};
    }(foos[i].id);
    foos[i].addEventListener('click', f);
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6e4NC/2/)

Comment: Alternatively, you can bind the event listener inside the inner function. `function (fooId) { foos[i].addEventListener('click', function() {doFoo(fooId)}); }(foos[i].id);`. Its more readable, IMO.

Comment: @Notulysses - Thanks for the answer. Can you point me to where I can read more about that syntax where you appended the }(foos[i].id);? i.e. I would like to know how/why your solution works.

Comment: @Jed : Glad to help you!Link : [JavaScript closures](http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62)

Comment: Also, @Jed, [Ben Alman's introduction to the 'Immediately-Invoked Function Expression' ('IIFE')](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

Comment: @Notulysses - For better readability, wouldn't it be better to replace "}(foos[i].id);" with, simply, "}(fooId);"? I've tested it and it works fine, but I'm not 100% sure that there is something inherently bad about doing so.

Comment: @Jed : it doesn't really matter, I've written that way just to underscore the changing `id` property in the loop

Answer (score 2):

```
function doFoo(id) {
    document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += "<li>You clicked Foo " + id + "</li>";
}

var foos = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
for (i = 0; i < foos.length; i++) {
    foos[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        doFoo(e.target.id);
    });
}
```

The event has the target, make use of that
http://jsfiddle.net/6e4NC/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < foos.length; i++) {
    var fooId = foos[i].id;
    foos[i].addEventListener('click', function (e, args) {
        doFoo(e);
});

function doFoo(e) {
    var fooId = e.target.id || e.srcElement.id;
    document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += "<li>You clicked Foo " + fooId + "</li>";
}
```

Comment: Won't work in Firefox.

Comment: Edited to use event.SrcElement. Thanks!

Comment: Still won't work. `event` will not be defined.

Comment: Nevermind. I am blind!!!